# perl regular expressions replacement

Tags: regex, perl

I haven't been able to figure out how to deal with a specific regex problem.

Say I have the a big string that consists of lots of phrases in square brackets. A phrase label (eg `S` or `VP`), a token (eg `w` or `wSf`), a slash next to that token and then the token's description, (eg `CC` or `VBD_MS3`).

So here's an example string:

```
[S w#/CC] [VP mSf/VBD_MS3]
```

I want to delete the whole first bracketed phrase and put the w inside of it with the second phrase, like this:

```
[VP wmSf/VBD_MS3]
```

Is that even possible using regular expressions?

---

Edit:
Okay the pattern is:

```
[ <label> w#/<label>] [<label> <word>/<label> <word>/<label> <word>/<label>...]
```

(the second bracketed phrase could have one to any number of / pairs)

where  can be any sequence of capital letters that might include an underscore, and word can a sequence of anything that's not whitespace (ie digits/characters/special characters).

Comment: you mentioned lots of phrases, can you give generic description of your objective instead of the two phrase example

Comment: Is the hash sign really part of the first phrase? You do not mention it in the description.

Comment: yes, the hash is part of the phrase. but i don't need it when i attach the w to the word in the second phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the actual form or positions, one of these forms might work (untested):

`s{\[S (\w+)#/\w+\] (\[VP )(\w+/\w+\])}{$2$1$3}g`
or
`s{\[(?:S/VP) (\w+)#/\w+\] (\[(?:S/VP) )(\w+/\w+\])}{$2$1$3}g`
or
`s{\[(?:S/VP)\s+(\w+)#/\w+\]\s+(\[(?:S/VP)\s+)(\w+/\w+\])}{$2$1$3}g`

**Edit**
Since your edit has included this pattern
`[ <label> w#/<label>] [<label> <word>/<label> <word>/<label> <word>/<label>...]`
it makes it easier to come up with a regex that should work.

Good luck!

```
use strict;
use warnings;


$/ = undef;

my $data = <DATA>;


my $regex = qr{

      \[\s*                         #= Start of token phrase '['
          (?&label) \s+                 # <label> then whitespace's
          ((?&word))                    # Capture $1 - token word, end grp $1
          [#]/(?&label)                   # '#'/<label>
          \s*
      \]                            #= End of token phrase ']'
      \s*
    (                             # Capture grp $2
      \[\s*                         #= Start of normal phrase '['
          (?&label) \s+                 # <label> then whitespace's
    )                             # End grp $2
    (                             # Capture grp $3
          (?&word)/(?&label)            # First <word>/<label> pair
          (?:                     
             \s+(?&word)/(?&label)      # Optional, many <word>/<label> pair's
          )*                      
          \s*
      \]                            #= End of normal phrase ']'
    )                             # End grp $3

   (?(DEFINE)               ## DEFINE's:
     (?<label> \w+)             # <label> - 1 or more word characters
     (?<word>  [^\s\[\]]+ )     # <word>  - 1 or more NOT whitespace, '[' nor ']'
   )
}x;


$data =~ s/$regex/$2$1$3/g;

print $data;

__DATA__

[S w#/CC] [VP mSf/VBD_MS3]
```

Output:
`[VP wmSf/VBD_MS3]`

**Edit2**
"if the label of the character is PP, and if the next phrase's label is NP, then change the next phrase's label to PP as well when joining. eg. input: [PP w#/IN] [NP something/NN] output: [PP wsomething/NN]"

Sure, without adding too many new capture groups, it can be done with a callback.
Actually, there are many ways to do this, including regex conditionals. I think the
simplest method is with a callback, where the logic for all label decisions can be made.

```
use strict;
use warnings;


$/ = undef;

my $data = <DATA>;


my $regex = qr{

   ( \[\s*                  # 1 - Token phrase label
         (?&label)         
         \s+
   )
         (                  # 2 - Token word
            (?&word)
         )         
         [#]/(?&label)
         \s*
     \]
     \s*

   ( \[\s*                  # 3 - Normal phrase label
         (?&label)
         \s+
   )
      # insert token word ($2) here
   (                        # 4 - The rest ..
         (?&word)/(?&label)
         (?: \s+ (?&word)/(?&label) )*                      
         \s*
      \]
   )

   (?(DEFINE)               ## DEFINE's:
     (?<label> \w+)             # <label> - 1 or more word characters
     (?<word>  [^\s\[\]]+ )     # <word>  - 1 or more NOT whitespace, '[' nor ']'
   )
}x;


$data =~ s/$regex/ checkLabel($1,$3) ."$2$4"/eg;


sub checkLabel
{
   my ($p1, $p2) = @_;
   if ($p1 =~ /\[\s*PP\s/ && $p2 =~ /(\[\s*)NP(\s)/) {
      return $1.'PP'.$2;
      # To use the formatting of the token label, just 'return $p1;'
   }
   return $p2;
}


print $data;

__DATA__

[PP w#/CC] [ NP     mSf/VBD_MS3]
```

Comment: thanks @sln, this code really helped me learn more about regex!

i've modified the help on this page and successfully gotten everything i need, except one issue.
is it possible to do the following:
- always join the character before # to the next phrase BUT
- if the label of the character is PP, and if the next phrase's label is NP, then change the next phrase's label to PP as well when joining. 
eg. input: [PP w#/IN] [NP something/NN]
    output: [PP wsomething/NN] <-- so in this case the second phrase's label has changed from NP to PP.

Comment: No problem, added **Edit2** .

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

```
s|\[S w#/CC\] \[(VP) (mSf/VBD_MS3)\]|[$1 w$2]|;
```

Now what *patterns* are you looking for?

You could even do this:

```
s|\[S (w)#/CC\] \[(VP) (mSf/VBD_MS3)\]|[$2 $1$3]|;
```

Comment: I think you are not capturing w, shouldn't it be
`s|\[S (w#)/CC\] \[(VP) (mSf/VBD_MS3)\]|[$2 $1$3]|;`

Comment: okay i'm confused... should it not be "s/string/replacent/g"? And what do the numbers mean? $1, $2 etc? i've been using basic regex for a while but when it comes to this stuff i don't get it, and i have tried tutorials..

Comment: Hi Axeman thanks that helped. I edited the question and added the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than create a magic regex to do the whole job, why not separate the line into phrases, operate on them then return them. This then follows the same logic that you just explained.

This then cleaner, more readable (especially if you add comments) and robust. Of course you will need to tailor to your needs: for example you may want to make the `/` separated portions into key/value pairs (does the order matter? if not make a hashref); perhaps you don't need to split on `/` if you never need to modify the label; etc.

Edit per comments:
This takes a literal `w` before a `#`, stores it, removes the phrase, then tacks the `w` onto the next phrase. If thats what you need then have at it. Of course I'm sure there are edge cases to look out for, so backup and test first!

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while( my $line = <DATA> ) {
  #separate phrases, then split phases into whitespace separated pieces
  my @phrases = map { [split /[\s]/] } ($line =~ /\[([^]]+)\]/g);

  my $holder; # holder for 'w' (not really needed if always 'w')
  foreach my $p (@phrases) { # for each phrase
    if ($p->[1] =~ /(w)#/) { # if the second part has 'w#'
      $holder = $1; # keep the 'w' in holder
      $p = undef; #empty to mark for cleaning later
      next; #move to next phrase
    }

    if ($holder) { #if the holder is not empty
      $p->[1] = $holder . $p->[1]; # add the contents of the holder to the second part of this phrase
      $holder = undef; # and then empty the holder
    }
  }

  #remove emptied phrases
  @phrases = grep { $_ } @phrases;

  #reconstitute the line
  print join( ' ', map { '[' . join(' ', @$_) . ']' } @phrases), "\n";
}

__DATA__
[S w#/CC] [VP mSf/VBD_MS3]
```

Again, it may seem amazing what you can do with one regex, but what happens if your boss comes in and says, "you know, that thing you wrote to do X works great, but now it needs to do Y too". This is why I like to keep nicely separate logic for each logical step.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. However, it assigns the initial "w" to ALL following phrases.. not the one that immediately follows. How do we add that constraint? (Because this code is a little beyond me :(  )

Comment: to get it absolutely right, you want to remove the phrase `[]` if it has `#` or if it has `S` (which one?) and then tack the character before the `#` onto the next item?

Comment: yes, that's right. the phrase i want to remove is one that has a w, but the label could be S or anything else.

Comment: okay a question. in the foreach(@phrases) loop, how can we find the length of a single phrase? what is the type of "p"? i tried scalar, and length, doesn't work. How do we get the number of space-delimited words within a [ phrase ]? Also what is $1? I tried $0 and got the name of the perl file!

Comment: `$p` is an array reference (use `ref $p` to see it) (remember that `$p` is an element of the `@phrases` array, so `$p` is really a row in the @array matrix if you like). The elements of `@$p` are the elements of the phrase, split by whitespace, so the total length is the sum of the lengths of the elements (plus n-1 for the whitespace). $1 is the matched result from the regex matching `w`. That bit of the code really was leftover from when I wasn't sure if you wanted a literal `w` or the char before the `#` or the char after an `S`, so that probably can be removed if it will always be `w`

Comment: again its up to you if you want to use a highly involved regex, but it is not as extensible. I always think in terms of the actual logic needed, then do those things one at a time. You need the separate phrases, then you need the elements of the phrases, then those that have w, then tack the w on the next thing, then recombine. If you needed to add something else to the logic, isn't it easier to add something if it isn't intricately knit to the exact job? I think so: use a regex for one job at a time, not all of the jobs at once. Just my $0.02

Comment: I'm using this version, yes it does help (especially for a beginner at regex!) as there are definitely edits to be made and also case specific phrase-processing.

But I still can't see $p's contents. I tried "ref $p" (is that what you meant?) but that returns nothing. If I print it out simply, I get an array address. I can print them out individually $p->[n] as required... but is there anyway to count the elements of p, so that I can traverse through them? Since it's a row of elements, I thought I could further split this up by split(" ",$p)... but that was an obvious mistake.

Comment: If you don't know how to count the elements of an array, then what you are telling me is that you first need to curl up with the [modern perl](http://onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/) book (its free!). To this specific question, you can iterate over elements of an array(ref) with `foreach my $elem (@$p) { #do stuff with $elem }` or count the elements with `my $num_elem = @$p` (an array in scalar context returns its number of elements, if you don't know contexts then, please, read the book, it will help).

Comment: remember, `$p` is an array reference, to get its elements you need to dereference to a standard array `my @elements = @{ $p };` or for short (when the reference is in a simple scalar) `my @elements = @$p;`. You can often skip the assignment of the dereferenced array and simply use `@$p` where you would have used `@elements`.

Comment: Ah! The "@" preceding the $p was what I was missing. I do know how to handle simple arrays :) Thanks a lot for all the help :)

Comment: if that was the problem then I suggest [`perldoc perlreftut`](http://p3rl.org/reftut)

Answer (score 0):

```
#/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $str = "[S w#/CC] [VP mSf/VBD_MS3]";
$str =~ s{\[S w#/CC\]\s*(\[VP\s)(.+)}{$1w$2} and print $str;
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer to provide some context and explanation?